# How exactly python converts arbitrary object into list?

Tags: python, list, object, casting, duck-typing

### Documentation [says](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-list):

> The constructor builds a list whose items are the same and in the same
>   order as iterable‘s items. iterable may be either a sequence, a
>   container that supports iteration, or an iterator object. If iterable
>   is already a list, a copy is made and returned, similar to
>   iterable[:]...

But if I have an object `a` of my class `A`, that implements `__iter__`, `__len__` and `__getitem__`, which interface is used by `list(a)` to iterate my object and what logic is behind this?

### My quick experimenting confuses me:

```python
class A(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        print '__iter__ was called'
        return iter([1,2,3])
    def __len__(self):
        print '__len__ was called'
        return 3
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        print '__getitem(%i)__ was called' % index
        return index+1

a = A()
list(a)
```

Outputs

```
__iter__ was called
__len__ was called
[1, 2, 3]
```

`A.__iter__` was called first, ok. But why then `A.__len__` was called? And then why `A.__getitem__` was not called?

### Then I turned `__iter__` to a generator

*And this changed the order of magic method calls!*

```python
class B(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        print '__iter__ was called'
        yield 1
        yield 2
        yield 3
    def __len__(self):
        print '__len__ was called'
        return 3
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        print '__getitem(%i)__ was called' % index
        return index+1      

b = B()
list(b)
```

Outputs

```
__len__ was called
__iter__ was called
[1, 2, 3]
```

Why `B.__len__` was called first now? But why then `B.__getitem__` was not called, and conversion was done with `B.__iter__`?

And what confuses me most is why the order of calls of `__len__` and `__iter__` is different in cases of `A` and `B`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call order didn't change. `__iter__` still got called first, but calling `__iter__` doesn't run the function body immediately when `__iter__` is a generator. The `print` only happens once `next` gets called.

`__len__` getting called is an implementation detail. Python wants a hint for how much space to allocate for the list, so [it calls `_PyObject_LengthHint`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/listobject.c#l850) on your object, which uses `len` if the object supports it. It is expected that calling `len` on an object will generally be fast and free of visible side effects.

Comment: Thank's a lot, this completely clarifies everything. Shame on me that I forgot  that calling generator function does not run function body before the first .next() call.